# Unity autorecompile (loop)

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

**What I use:**

Unity Hub 2.4.2, Unity V. 2021.2.0a5, Apple MacBook Pro M1 16 GB Ram

[image]

**Problem:**

I've created a new C# script and the script is autorecompiling every minute.

I have already disabled autorecompile and I have no IDE (Visual Studio) open. I have already restarted the PC, closed the program and opened it again.

Comment: I suggest, ask this question in [Unity Forums](https://forum.unity.com/). Because if you have no **IDE** open, probably, Unity autocompile it without asking or detect anything that changed. Or re-importing C# script every minute.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've already asked the question in the Unity forum. I'm just trying my luck here too. Unity already crashed because of this issue. (I also report the bug.)

Comment: Your question is opinion based, it will probably closed soon.

Comment: When I need help and I'm kicked out the door. That hurts.

Comment: Noone is trying to kick you out nor trying to be unhelpful. This community has spesific rules for spesific reason. Your question is directly a bug not a programming question. Also, it is opinion question that's why I didn't suggest to ask here but in Unity Forum.

Comment: You're using an alpha version of Unity, issues are guaranteed to exist. Go back to an official release, where probably this issue is not present.